# Asp .Net Custom membership parameters from web.config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am currently writting a custom membership provider for asp .net and the problem that I am having is that I don't know how to give parameters to the custom membership provider in the same way that you give to the standard asp .net membership providers in the web.config file like password length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you derive your own class from `MembershipProvider` you have to override the `Initialize()` method, it has following signature:

```
public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config);
```

The `System.Collections.NameValueCollection` is a dictionary where you find the options written in the `web.config` file. These options are given in the same way you specify options for "standard" providers (as attributes). Each dictionary entry has the key of the attribute name and as value the attribute's value (as `string`).

```
public  class MyMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
    {
        base.Initialize(name, config);

        _enablePasswordReset = config.GetBoolean("enablePasswordReset", true);
    }
}
```

Where, in my example, `GetBoolean()` is an extension method declared somewhere as follow:

```
public static bool GetBoolean(this NameValueCollection config,
    string valueName, bool? defaultValue)
{
    object obj = config[valueName];
    if (obj == null)
    {
        if (!defaultValue.HasValue)
            throw new WarningException("Required field has not been specified.");

        return defaultValue.Value;
    }

    bool value = defaultValue;
    if (obj is Boolean)
        return (bool)obj;

    IConvertible convertible = obj as IConvertible;
    try
    {
        return convertible.ToBoolean(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        if (!defaultValue.HasValue)
            throw new WarningException("Required field has invalid format.");

        return defaultValue.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly how I've done it in the past, after you call `base.Initialize` fill in the rest of your configuration values, setting suitable defaults or throwing exceptions as needed for missing mandatory parameters.

Answer (score 2):

If your provider derives from `MembershipProvider : ProviderBase` than all the configuration should be loaded and applied form web.config.

Consider implementing custom `IPrincipal` and/or `IIdentity` - it's sometimes a better extension point and since not everyone is aware of it it's often not used.

Answer (score 1):

In the same way you define the standard .net membership:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyCustomMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="30">
                <providers>
                    <clear />
                    <add name="MyCustomMembershipProvider" type="Namespace.MyCustomMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="db_ConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Encrypted" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="/" />
                    <add name="StandardMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="db_ConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Encrypted" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" applicationName="/" />
                </providers>
    </membership>
```